# addeventlistener to document.currentScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, addeventlistener

I'm trying to add an eventlistener to the current executing script like this:

```
EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener.apply(this.currentScript,["load",somefunction()]]
```

I can see the event on this script in chrome dev tools but for some reason it won't fire.
it's even possible to add an eventlistener to a script tag that already started to execute? and if it is what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What event listener do you expect to fire on a JavaScript *script*? Or do you want to add the event-listener to the `<script>` element itself; although the question remains: what events do you expect to be fired?

Comment: @DavidThomas you can see in the code the event i'm listening for ("load").
and this is a reference to the document so this.currentScript will return the javascript element.

Answer (score 0):

> it's even possible to add an eventlistener to a script tag that already started to execute?

Possible? Yes. Would it be of any use? I don't think so. AFAIK the 'load' event would have already fired at that point.

The only time I've found use for 'load' events on script tags are when dynamically creating them, something like:

```
function loadError(oError) {
  throw new URIError("The script " + oError.target.src + " didn't load correctly.");
}

function prefixScript(url, onloadFunction) {
  var newScript = document.createElement("script");
  newScript.onerror = loadError;
  if (onloadFunction) { newScript.onload = onloadFunction; }
  document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(newScript, document.currentScript);
  newScript.src = url;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement